# Numexpr not found in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numexpr

I install numexpr package via pip on my Windows 7 machine:

```
pip list | grep numexpr
numexpr (2.4.6)
```

but when I open ipython and trying to use [df.query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) it shows an error:

```
ImportError: 'numexpr' not found. Cannot use engine='numexpr' for query/eval if 'numexpr' is not installed
```

Than I checked whether it installed or not with pd.show_versions:

```
In [97]: pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.4.3.final.0
python-bits: 32
OS: Windows
OS-release: 7
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None

pandas: 0.17.1
nose: None
pip: 7.1.2
setuptools: 18.5
Cython: None
numpy: 1.10.1
scipy: 0.16.1
statsmodels: 0.6.1
IPython: 4.0.0
sphinx: None
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.4.2
pytz: 2015.7
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.0.0
tables: None
numexpr: None
matplotlib: 1.5.0
openpyxl: 2.3.1
xlrd: 0.9.4
xlwt: 1.0.0
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: 3.5.0
bs4: 4.4.1
html5lib: 1.0b8
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
Jinja2: 2.8
```

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/install.html#dependencies):

> **numexpr**: for accelerating certain numerical operations. numexpr uses multiple cores as well as smart chunking and caching to achieve large speedups. If installed, must be **Version 2.1 or higher**.

Comment: I installed it via pip using wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: Are you installing numexpr to the same place/version as pandas?

Comment: I installed them both with pip so I suggest that they should be in the same place. I'll check it to make sure

Comment: So I have them both installed in directory c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\, pandas `0.17.1` and numexpr `2.4.6`

Comment: Does `import numexpr` work? How are you attemping to run it - command line/gui/notebook etc... have you tried closing anything and re-opening to avoid any issues that could be caused by that?

Comment: thanks, I have an error `ImportError: DLL load failed:` So it's problem with installation of numexpr probably

Comment: But I don't understand why I have an issue with numexpr installation. I install it from `numexpr-2.4.6-cp34-none-win32.whl` and expect it to work without any additional actions.. Probably it's because I have numpy version `1.10.1` and numexpr isn't still portable for that version?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your last comment about compatibility of `numpy 1.10.1` and `numexpr`: I am not sure what numexpr version I used, but used it yesterday at home with `numpy 1.10.1` under `python 3.4` and it worked.

I am not an expert in using `pip` so maybe my hint is wrong but when I used `pip` to upgrade `numpy` under Ubuntu lately it updated only `numpy` for `python 2.7` which is installed in parallel on my machine.

As I use `python 3.4` for coding I had to install `pip3` to get it also upgraded for `python3`. Try if the installation works when using `pip3 install numexpr`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using windows not linux.

Comment: On my Windows machine I have Anaconda3 2.4.0. It installs with `python 3.5`, `numpy 1.10.1` and `numexpr 2.4.4`. Haven't tried to upgrade to `numexpr 2.4.6` though.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'numexpr' engine can not be found use the 'python' engine instead.
Open the eval.py file in pandas package and replace the

```
def eval(expr, parser='pandas', engine='numexpr'
```

with

```
def eval(expr, parser='pandas', engine='python'
```

Comment: Why would you ask OP to change the source code when they could just pass `engine='python'` as an argument?

Comment: Given that the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#pandas-eval-engines) states: *"You will achieve no performance benefits using eval() with engine='python' and may incur a performance hit"*, I don't think this would be useful for the OP.